# Is there a way to add a hint to a field in Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony4, sonata-admin

Is there a way to add a hint or some kind of explenation to a field in Sonata Admin?

Something like this:

```
[Label]*
[ -- The field -- ]
// here should be the description of the field
```

I did not find anything about this in the [docu](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/index.html), so I guess it is somehow done by some kind of template override or the like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll reading the [other documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/form_help_message.html) helps ;) - looks like it is simply inherited from [Symfony FormType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html).

For example:

```php
$formMapper->add('slug', TextType::class, [
    'help' => 'Used as URL or the linked page'
])
```